# Swift 4: 'init(_offset:)' is unavailable

Tags: swift4, xcode9

> Swift 4 : 'init(_offset:)' is unavailable

I am trying to expand variable names (enclosed by curly braces).

```
let message = "Hello {what}".expand(["what" : "world"])                
print(message) // Hello World
```

I used this for dynamic URL construction.

Up to Swift 3.2, it was working fine. When I tried to convert it to Swift 4, it's throwing the error mentioned above for this line:

```
let templateStartChar = "{".utf16[String.UTF16View.Index(_offset: 0)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is stuck with this, below is the solution :

In place of `_offset` I use `encodedOffset`

```
let templateStartChar = "{".utf16[String.UTF16View.Index(encodedOffset: 0)]
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Get `{` as UTF16?